# Focus a <li> inside <div> with overflow:auto

Tags: jquery, css

I have made an search function where you can navigate the results with your keyboard arrows. All results will show up in `li`'s inside a `div` with style:

```
overflow:auto; max-height: 100px;
```

I focus the first `li` with this code:

```
$('#searchInput').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode==40) {
        $('li:first').focus();
    }
});
```

The `div` with `overflow:auto` will then auto scroll so the first focused `li` won't be visible...

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/CZz9n/1/

Comment: What is the question/what isn't working the way you want it to?

Comment: @robooneus I think the part that isn’t working is the second-to-last paragraph. “The div with `overflow: auto` will then auto scroll so the first focused `li` won’t be visible.” When you press the down arrow like the text field in the demo says, the first item is selected but scrolls out of sight. It should be selected and stay visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scrolling down comes from the browser default behavior of interpreting the down arrow as a command to scroll down. To fix this, you just need to prevent the default behavior.

You have already prevented the default behavior in the `keydown` handler for the `li`s, which is just what we need. You used `return false`, but [`e.preventDefault()` is slightly safer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1357118/578288).

```js
$('#searchInput').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode==40) {
        e.preventDefault(); // add this
        $('li:first').focus();
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/mDVyb/)

Comment: Isn't `return false` a bit overkill? `e.preventDefault()` should suffice.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 I had forgotten [the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1357118/578288), so I had just copied the `return false` from the other lines. Yes, `e.preventDefault()` [works too](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/mDVyb/), and I guess it’s a bit safer.